# Getting error in multi-gpu training with pytorch lightning

Tags: pytorch-lightning

The below code works on a single GPU but throws an error while using multiple gpus
RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs

code

```
    def forward(                                                                
            self,                                                               
            input_ids,                                                          
            attention_mask=None,                                                
            decoder_input_ids=None,                                             
            decoder_attention_mask=None,                                        
            lm_labels=None                                                      
    ):                                                                          
        return self.model(                                                      
            input_ids,                                                          
            attention_mask=attention_mask,                                      
            decoder_input_ids=decoder_input_ids,                                
            decoder_attention_mask=decoder_attention_mask,                      
            labels=lm_labels,                                                   
        )                                                                       
                                                                                
    def _step(self, batch):                                                     
        lm_labels = batch["target_ids"]                                         
        # lm_labels[lm_labels[:, :] == self.tokenizer.pad_token_id] = -100      
        outputs = self(                                                         
            input_ids=batch["source_ids"],                                      
            attention_mask=batch["source_mask"],                                
            lm_labels=lm_labels,                                                
            decoder_attention_mask=batch['target_mask']                         
        )                                                                       
                                                                                
        loss = outputs[0]                                                       
                                                                                
        return loss    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):                                  
        loss = self._step(batch)                                                
        return {"loss": loss}
```

The loss value is a scaler:
tensor(12.8875, device='cuda:1', grad_fn=NllLossBackward)
What could be the reason behind this error?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "training_trial.py", line 390, in 
trainer.fit(model)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 510, in fit
results = self.accelerator_backend.train()
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 57, in train
return self.train_or_test()
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 74, in train_or_test
results = self.trainer.train()
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 561, in train
self.train_loop.run_training_epoch()
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 549, in run_training_epoch
batch_output = self.run_training_batch(batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 704, in run_training_batch
self.optimizer_step(optimizer, opt_idx, batch_idx, train_step_and_backward_closure)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 490, in optimizer_step
using_lbfgs=is_lbfgs,
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/lightning.py", line 1296, in optimizer_step
optimizer.step(closure=optimizer_closure)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py", line 286, in step
self.__optimizer_step(*args, closure=closure, profiler_name=profiler_name, **kwargs)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py", line 144, in _*optimizer_step
optimizer.step(closure=closure, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py", line 67, in wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/optimization.py", line 318, in step
loss = closure()
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 699, in train_step_and_backward_closure
self.trainer.hiddens
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 802, in training_step_and_backward
self.backward(result, optimizer, opt_idx)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 829, in backward
result.closure_loss, optimizer, opt_idx, *args, **kwargs
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 109, in backward
model.backward(closure_loss, optimizer, opt_idx, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/lightning.py", line 1162, in backward
loss.backward(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 221, in backward
torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/**init**.py", line 126, in backward
grad_tensors* = *make_grads(tensors, grad_tensors*)
File "/home/nvarshn2/.conda/envs/pytorch_lightning_new_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/**init**.py", line 50, in _make_grads
raise RuntimeError("grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs")
RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs

Answer (score 0):

Adding training_step_end()
Reference: https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/4073

```
 def training_step_end(self, training_step_outputs):
        return {'loss': training_step_outputs['loss'].sum()}
```